# INSERT WITH NOT EXISITS

Tags: sql, insert, exists, interbase

I'd like to combine an insert query with a "where not exists"

Here my SQL :

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ACT_ORDER, MNU_ACTION, ACT_STATUT, ACT_BEFORE, ACT_AFTER)
SELECT (1,'acOuvPOS', 'T', 'T', NULL)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE  (MNU_ACTION ='acOuvPOS' AND ACT_STATUT = 'T' AND ACT_BEFORE= 'T');
```

But when I execute the SQL I have this problem

> Invalid token. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -104. Token unknown
>   - line 2, char 8. ,.

How can I resolve this please
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL)?

Comment: Your missing a closing `)` before the terminating `;`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I miss the closing ) when coping the requet, I use Interbase 6.0.2

Comment: I think that `SELECT` needs a `FROM` clause.

Comment: NO Sorry , I have this error , Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, char 6.
FROM.

Comment: What is the logic behind your query?

Comment: is to Insert a record if isn't exist in the table

Comment: Errors aside, the `NOT EXISTS` clause will always be the same, regardless of which record is being selected.  You might want to rethink your logic.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ACT_ORDER, MNU_ACTION, ACT_STATUT, ACT_BEFORE, ACT_AFTER)
SELECT 1,'acOuvPOS', 'T', 'T', NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MNU_ACTION ='acOuvPOS' AND ACT_STATUT = 'T' AND ACT_BEFORE= 'T')

Comment: Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 1, char 0.
IF.

Comment: Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, char 36.
WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply say :

IF (
    NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE  (MNU_ACTION ='acOuvPOS' AND ACT_STATUT = 'T' AND ACT_BEFORE= 'T')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE 
        (ACT_ORDER, MNU_ACTION, ACT_STATUT, ACT_BEFORE, ACT_AFTER)
    (1,'acOuvPOS', 'T', 'T', NULL)
END